# Show additional info when RecyclerView is clicked

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-relativelayout

I have a RecyclerView with a list of names being pulled from a firebase realtime database, as well with phone numbers, emails and addresses. I have created a layout for the cards shown in RecyclerView. I want them to only display the name and image until clicked. Once clicked they expand and show the phone number, email and address. I have done all this but the final problem I am facing is with setVisibility for the RelativeLayout inside the layout.xml for RecyclerView, since it's a different xml from the one that belongs to the activity my app keeps crashing. I have tried multiple solutions for problems similar to mine but I could never find someone with the same problem that I was facing.

Now if I use this code:

```
mUserInfoLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.user_additional_info_layout);
mUserInfoLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

I get this error

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
```

However If I use the code provided below nothing happens the Layout stays visible.

My MainActivity.java OnCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //Firebase
    mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    mUserDatabase.keepSynced(true);

    //mUserSingleMainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.user_single_main_layout);


    mUsersList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.users_list);
    mUsersList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mUsersList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    View usersingleView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.users_single_layout, null);
    mUserInfoLayout = (RelativeLayout) usersingleView.findViewById(R.id.user_additional_info_layout);
    mUserInfoLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    //Buttons
    mUserAdd = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.user_add_btn);

    mUserAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent createuserIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateUserActivity.class);
            startActivity(createuserIntent);

        }
    });


}
```

My activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/user_add_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"/>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/users_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

My user_single_layout.xml the layout file used in RecyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/user_single_image"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/account_circle" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/user_single_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/display_name_users"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:textSize="18sp" />


  <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/user_additional_info_layout"
     android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@id/user_single_name"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
     android:layout_marginStart="100dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_phone_image"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/user_single_phone"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_phone_black_24dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_email_image"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/user_single_email"
        android:layout_below="@+id/user_phone_image"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_address_image"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/user_single_address"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_map_marker_black_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_single_phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/user_phone_image"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Phone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_single_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/user_single_phone"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/user_email_image"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Email" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_single_address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/user_single_email"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/user_address_image"
        android:text="Address" />

  </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the user_single_layout.xml I want to make the "@+id/user_additional_info_layout" RelativeLayout invisible programatically inside MainActivity.java

Comment: You can simply use ExpandableListView otherwise use LinearLayout and make a transition to expand and collapse the view. LinearLayout works better I have the actual codes in Kotlin I can send If you are interested in it.

Comment: Please do, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

**My answer is focused on the Fragment lifecycle. The Activity lifecycle is different and does not contain the method I suggested.**

The problem is the view that you are trying to access is null. The view is not yet inflated in the onCreate method and is therefore not yet available.

No view related logic should be executed within onCreate().

You need to use the onViewCreated() method to access your views which has the following signature:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    
}
```

Therefore I suggest you move all of your view related logic into this method.

Answer (score 0):

First, move your code to recyclerView adapter.
Second, make relativeLayout visibility to gone and change it to linearLayout.
Third, use this code for expanding it.

```
private fun animateView(
view: View,
duration: Long,
initialHeight: Int,
targetHeight: Int,
onAnimationEnd: () -> Unit = {}
  ) {
      view.apply {
       val animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(initialHeight, targetHeight)
         animator.addUpdateListener {
          layoutParams.height = it.animatedValue as Int
          requestLayout()
          if (it.animatedValue as Int > 2) {
              //Make the view visible in java 
              //yourview.setVisibility(View.Visible)
              show()
          }
      }
       animator.addListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
           override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
              layoutParams.height = targetHeight
              onAnimationEnd.invoke()
           }

           override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator) {

           }

           override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator) {}
           override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator) {}
       })
       animator.interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()
       animator.duration = duration
       animator.start()
   }
  }
  fun View.expandAnimation(duration: Long) {
     measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
     ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
     val initialHeight = 0
     val targetHeight = measuredHeight

     layoutParams.height = 0
     animateView(this, duration, initialHeight, targetHeight)
    }

 fun View.collapseAnimation(duration: Long) {
     val initialHeight = measuredHeight
     val targetHeight = 0

    animateView(this, duration, initialHeight, targetHeight) {
       hide()
    }
  }

 fun View.hide() {
    this.apply {
       visibility = View.GONE
   }
 }

 fun View.show() {
    this.apply {
       visibility = View.VISIBLE
   }
  }
```

You can easily convert this code to java
sry I don't have time to convert it myself